# Lipschitz equivalent definition.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Is Lipschitz continuous equivalent to this definition, f is Lipschitz continuous on [a,b] if for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for every finite collection of intervals $\{(a_i,b_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ of open intervals in $(a,b)$, if $\sum_{i=1}^n [b_i-a_i] < \delta$ then $\sum_{i=1}^n |f(b_i)-f(a_i)|< \epsilon$.

Comment: No, because absolute continuity is for disjoint intervals. In this definition, the intervals don't need to be disjoint.

Comment: FYI, this result is due to [Grigorii Mikhailovich Fichtenholz (1888-1959)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorii_Fichtenholz). See pp. 456-457 of [*Note sur les fonctions absolument continues*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015011443333;view=1up;seq=452) (1922) and pp. 288-289 of the Russian version [*Об абсолютно непрерывных функциях*](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/f1b649d77a22407300d74a9c55b192e3/sm6853.pdf) (1923).

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is absolutely continuous we can write $f(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{x}g(t)dt$ for some integrable function $g.$ Let $x$ be a
Lebesgue point of $g.$ Taking $a_{j}=x,b_{j}=x+\frac{\delta }{2n}$ for $%
1\leq j\leq n$ (the same interval is repeated $n$ times) we get  $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\left\vert f(x+\frac{\delta }{%
2n})-f(x)\right\vert <\epsilon .$ Hence $n\left\vert
\int\limits_{x}^{x+\delta /(2n)}g(t)dt\right\vert <\epsilon .$ This holds
for all $n$ and since $x$ is a Lebesgue point of $g$ we get $\left\vert
g(x)\right\vert \leq \frac{2\epsilon }{\delta }.$ We have proved that $g$ is
an $L^{\infty }$ function. Hence $f$ is Lipschitz.